# contextlib.redirect_stdout in Python2.7

Tags: python, redirectstandardoutput

I use Python2.7 and I want the function: [contextlib.redirect_stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout).
I mean, I want to redirect the output of specific function (not the all program).
The problem is - only Python3 supports "context.redirect_stdout" and no Python2.7.

Someone know how can I use the same function in Python2.7 or to implement the same idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://contextlib2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 9):

Something like this should do the job if you're not worried about re-using the same context manager object.

```
import sys
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def redirect_stdout(target):
    original = sys.stdout
    try:
        sys.stdout = target
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = original
```

Comment: Is it change the all program sdtout?
because I have some threads in the same process..

Comment: It does more or less the same thing as `redirect_stdout` from Python 3's `contextlib`, whose docs [say it is not suitable for threaded applications](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=contextlib.redirect_stdout#contextlib.redirect_stdout). I haven't tested it, but it should redirect `stdout` globally for all threads. I'm not aware of any way to redirect it in only the current thread.