# Within contextlib.redirect_stdout() the print()-function causes an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, writetofile, console-output

I tried to redirect the entire console output of a specific part of my python code to a textfile following the advice of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197009/how-can-i-redirect-print-output-of-a-function-in-python/14197079#14197079).

According to that post, it should work with contextlib.redirect_stdout(), but *when the first print()-command appears* within my custom function custom_function_with_internal_print_calls(), it throws the *AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'*.

```
dummy_file = "dummy_textfile.txt"  # file to which the stdout shall be redirected

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(dummy_file):
    # Direct print()-function call
    print("Informative string which shall go to the textfile instead of the console.")

    # Indirect print()-function calls (internally)
    custom_function_with_internal_print_calls(**kwargs)
```

**EDIT:**
In my particular case, instead of a print()-function within the with-environment, I have a custom function which has internal calls to Python's built-in print()-function. It shouldn't matter if the print()-function appears inside another function, or directly at the top-level to reproduce the error.

**Options already tried:**
Other workarounds don't seem to provide the solution I'm looking for,such as

[redefining the print()-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197009/how-can-i-redirect-print-output-of-a-function-in-python/14197101#14197101) or

[writing a decorator for python 2.7x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226221/contextlib-redirect-stdout-in-python2-7/44226422#44226422) (as I'm using python 3.7x),
or also

[redirecting the print()-function to a file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152762/how-to-redirect-print-output-to-a-file-using-python/7152903#7152903) via `print('Filename:', filename, file=f)`.
The latter would mean in my case to pass a file-handler to all sub-functions in my enclosed function of choice, which is too much extra code modification for this special case.

I hope to be able to employ just the environment `with contextlib.redirect_stdout(dummy_file):` wrapped around my function in order to redirect every console output of this very function to the *dummy_file*.

The [documentation of contextlib.redirect_stdout()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=contextlib.redirect_stdout#contextlib.redirect_stdout) doesn't help me either.
Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: Post your whole code.

Comment: The posted code does not contain a reference to an attribute named `write`, so I don't see how we can help.

Comment: Please post a proper [mcve] (not "your whole code" - only the minimal code required to reproduce the issue).

Comment: @JohnGordon I guess we can assume that `print_out_all_TIFF_Tags_n_filter_for_desired_TAGs` contains either `sys.stdout.write()` or `print()` calls (the later being mostly a wrapper around the first).

Comment: I've just edited now my post. Exactly, the print()-function causes the error, and it doesn't matter apparently at which nested level it is called (within my custom function). Anyway, I've solved the problem already as can be seen in my answer below. I have to pass a filehandler instead of a filepath to the contextlib.redirect_stdout() - function.

Comment: I'm about to open another question, because I'd like to redirect as well internal calls of via subprocess.call(cmd_string, stdout=filehandler) to the dummy-textfile, but it exists with the error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution via passing a **file-handler** "f" to the function `contextlib.redirect_stdout(f)` **instead of the filepath** *dummy_file*, as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python/22434262#22434262).

```
dummy_file = "dummy_textfile.txt"  # file to which the stdout shall be redirected

with open(dummy_file, 'w') as f:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
        # Indirect print()-function calls (internally)
        custom_function_with_internal_print_calls(**kwargs)
```

With this, all print()-function calls write to the dummy_file and restores the standard console output afterwards.

Comment: I was about to post a comment suggesting you were very probably passing a filename (string) instead of a file object xD

Comment: Hahaha, well, fortunately I was faster :D